# Using link_to make an image the link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to link this image to **profile_path(thing.user)**

```
<%= image_tag thing.user.photo.url(:small), { :class=>"rounded_square" ,
    style: "margin-left:8px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" } %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`link_to` should take a block if nothing helps:

```
<%= link_to profile_path(thing.user) do %>
    <%= image_tag thing.user.photo.url(:small), { :class=>"rounded_square" ,
style: "margin-left:8px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
= link_to somewhere_path(some_object) do
  = image_tag some_object.url, class: 'rounded_square'
end
```

The return value of the block becomes the content for the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with nested erb.

```
<%= link_to "#{image_tag(yourimagepath)}", "link_path" %>
```

Should look something like this.

```
     <%= link_to "#{image_tag thing.user.photo.url(:small), 
        { :class=>'rounded_square' , style: "margin-left:8px; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;" }}", 
       "profile_path(thing.user)" %>
```